# Find all combinations of N items in N groups without duplicates of item combos (python)?

Tags: python, math, iteration

I'm trying to figure out a way of calculating all possible combinations of features of a certain product and have them returned as a list, without duplicates.

I have the items (features of the product) grouped in this kind of manner:

```
a
   a1
   a2
   a3

b
   b1
   b2

c
   c1
   c2
   c3
   c4
```

The number of groups and items are unknown, so there are in fact N groups and N items.

Example combinations:

```
# Combinations with 3 groups
a1_b1_c1
a1_b2_c1
a1_b3_c1
...and so on

# Combinations with 4 groups
a1_b1_c1_d1
a1_b2_c1_d1
a1_b3_c1_d1
...and so on
```

I would consider `a1_b2_c3` and `a1_c3_b2` to be duplicates, and I would not want any duplicates in the returned list.

A product without all features, such as `a1_b2` or `b2` would not be a valid product and thus I do not want those in the returned list either.

I've looked into itertools but I'm stuck.
Any ideas?

Comment: [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely want itertools.product:

```
import itertools

for i in itertools.product(['a1','a2','a3'], ['b1','b2'],['c1','c2','c3','c4']):
    print '_'.join(i)
```

RETURNS

```
a1_b1_c1
a1_b1_c2
a1_b1_c3
...
a3_b2_c1
a3_b2_c2
a3_b2_c3
a3_b2_c4
```